# Wordpress Images Not Showing - URL for image shows as numbers

Tags: wordpress, image

Our Wordpress site suddenly stopped showing all 'featured' images. They're just blank. When we look at the source code it shows url(896). We have tried selecting the image again (which shows fine in the backend) but on the frontend it's still blank with an invalid URL. Any idea how to fix that and what may have happened? TIA!

To update: this below code is what's being used to pull the featured images (with the incorrect URL):

```
<div class="hero homepage relative-block" style="background-image:url(<?php the_field('hero_background_image'); ?>);<?php $hero_aspect_ratio = get_field('hero_aspect_ratio'); if( $hero_aspect_ratio ) { echo "padding-top:".$hero_aspect_ratio."%;"; } ?>"></div>
```

EDIT:-

The following also isn't grabbing any content. Any ideas?

```
<div class="page-content">
        <?php get_template_part('content-block-loop'); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share url?

Comment: Sure: http://www.sfspiritscomp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field `hero_background_image` returns attachment ID instead of the URL of the image. Use `wp_get_attachment_url($id)` with `get_field()` that returns the id, instead of `the_field()` that outputs the value to get the URL of the attachment/image:

```
<div class="hero homepage relative-block" style="background-image:url(<?php  echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_field('hero_background_image')); ?>);<?php $hero_aspect_ratio = get_field('hero_aspect_ratio'); if( $hero_aspect_ratio ) { echo "padding-top:".$hero_aspect_ratio."%;"; } ?>"></div>
```

Possible cause: if you use some metabox/custom fields plugin as MetaBox, Toolset Types or the ACF, someone has probably changed the settings for the field, to return the ID of the attachment instead of the URL. So that might also solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the URL is now empty - background-image: url();

Comment: @IVCatalina, I apologize, you need to output the wp_get_attachment_url with echo

Comment: i'm now having a problem with some of the post pages too. Please see my update below. Don't suppose you can help with this one, too?

Comment: You don't need to echo the get_template_part(), since it is a wrapper for PHP require()

Comment: Thanks... it was actually without but I tried adding it. It sadly doesn't work even without.

Comment: Well, you need to check the content of that template to see what it outputs, and check what global variable it needs. One advice also, you should post that as a separate question, since that is another issue. Avoid mixing issues on Stack Overflow, be precise, an separate issues.

Comment: I just did now; thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176945/page-content-not-showing-in-wordpress