# Page Content Not Showing in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

We did some updates to the site and since then the content blocks don't show in the frontend. This is what's being called:

```
<div class="page-content">
        <?php get_template_part('content-block-loop'); ?>
    </div>
```

And this is what it refers to:

```
<?php
$post_objects = get_field('page_content_blocks');
if( $post_objects ):
    foreach( $post_objects as $post_object):
        $args = array('orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_object->ID, 'content_block_cat', $args );
        if( get_field('disable_wpautop',$post_object->ID) ){
          remove_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');
        }
        include( locate_template( 'partials/content-blocks/'.$terms[0]->slug.".php" ) );
        add_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');
    endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And in partials/content-blocks/custom-content-block.php is has the following code:

```
<?php

$vertical_padding = "less-space";
$background_color = "white-bg";

if ( get_field('vertical_padding',$post_object->ID) ){
    $vertical_padding = get_field('vertical_padding',$post_object->ID);
}

if ( get_field('content_block_background_color',$post_object->ID) ){
    $background_color = get_field('content_block_background_color',$post_object->ID);
}

?>

<div class="panel <?php if( $vertical_padding != "none" ) { echo $vertical_padding; } ?> <?php echo $background_color; ?> relative-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column small-12">
            <?php $custom_content_block_content = get_field('content',$post_object->ID);
            if( $custom_content_block_content ){
                the_field('content',$post_object->ID);
            } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

We also had a similar problem with the images not showing and was able to change the PHP code to make it work. It seems what it calls (slugs etc) has all got knocked out. Really hoping there's a fix for the content, too, but I can't see it. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use the_content() to display post content.

```
function the_content( $more_link_text = null, $strip_teaser = false ) {
$content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );

/**
 * Filters the post content.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $content Content of the current post.
 */
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
$content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
echo $content;
}
```

The the_content() template tag fetches the content of the post, filters it, and then displays it. This is the meat and potatoes of each pass through The Loop.

Try this:

```
<?php

$vertical_padding = "less-space";
$background_color = "white-bg";

if ( get_field('vertical_padding',$post_object->ID) ){
  $vertical_padding = get_field('vertical_padding',$post_object->ID);
}

if ( get_field('content_block_background_color',$post_object->ID) ){
  $background_color = get_field('content_block_background_color',$post_object->ID);
}

?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<div class="panel <?php if( $vertical_padding != "none" ) { echo $vertical_padding; } ?> <?php echo $background_color; ?> relative-block">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column small-12">
        <?php $custom_content_block_content = get_field('content',$post_object->ID);
        if( $custom_content_block_content ){
            the_field('content',$post_object->ID);
        } ?>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The WordPress loop isn't active on your pages and by including the_content() should fix all the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you! Am not sure if that first section needed to go somewhere too - I tried it in functions and in the initial php file but get an error trying to call content. I did add the_content() above as requested, but unfortunately content still doesn't show.